# Which data structure can i use if i want to reduce its memory by half during the execution

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures

I want to half the number of elements that the data-structure contains. And I have to do that multiple times.
The problem is similar to this:
I have 'n' sorted integers and I have to add consecutive two numbers. Thus the number of the number of integers I am left with is n/2.And I have to loop this till I get a single number. ( I simplified the problem, I have to do other operations side by side)

I thought trying an array of size n, then thought I will create an array of size n/2 and will fill this new array, and finally will free the original array(was created using a pointer). Note that I also have to store the data I evaluated each time through the loop.

If I am not able to explain, please refer to this problem
[MIXTURE](https://www.codechef.com/problems/MIXTURES)

Comment: C or C++? They are different programming languages

Comment: With C you could update the array in place, then use `realloc()` to shrink the allocation. You don't need to copy to a new array.

Comment: It seems you just want the total sum of the array :)

Comment: no, actually that is just a simplification, I also have to do some other operations side by side

Comment: @rishabhjain There is no guarantee the memory will be "half the size".  The heap manager may still hold onto the memory, even after you `free` or `delete[]` the memory.

Comment: Use `std::queue`. Pop two elements, add them and push the result back into the queue until the queue has only one element. This is your result. You do all calculation in place and don't need to allocate and free memory

Comment: @molbdnilo it is mixing of the containers, in the problem that is troubling me

Comment: I suspect that you need a cleverer approach. (It smells like dynamic programming to me.)

Answer (score 2):

Use a pointer to memory allocated with `malloc` (or `calloc`, or similar), then resize it with `realloc`:

```
int main()
{
    int* myArray = malloc(50 * sizeof(int));   // gets you 50 integers
    // perform operations on myArray, accessing it like myArray[3]
    int* r = realloc(myArray, 25 * sizeof(int));
    if (r) {
        myArray = r;
    }
    // perform some more operations.
    free(myArray);  // free the memory once you are done with it
}
```

`realloc` returns a new pointer that points to memory of the same content as the pointer you passed before. Assign the result back to `myArray` like this to get the desired behavior, and when you don't need the array anymore, call `free` on it just like you would do normally if you haven't reallocated it.

Comment: i wont be able to fill it, that is the actual problem

Comment: If `realloc` fails, you leak the original allocation because you overwrite the original variable. That's why you should always save the result of `realloc` to another variable.

Comment: Good suggestion, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Which data structure can i use if i want to reduce its memory by half during the execution
>
> I want to half the number of elements that the data-structure contains. And I have to do that multiple times.

You can use any dynamically sized data structure, which is pretty much all data structures except the statically sized array.

Although, note that reducing the size of memory allocated for `std::vector` (upon calling `shrink_to_fit`) is technically not guaranteed to happen. Example using vector:

```
vec.resize(vec.size() / 2);
vec.shrink_to_fit();
```